# Global variable getting dereferanced

Tags: macos, cocoa, nib, objective-c++

I have a global variable called `NSTableView  *dataTableViewGlobal;` which I have stored in a c++ struct called `g`.

I have a subclass of `NSViewController` called `Window` which has a nib associated with it and is created when my program loads. Right now `Window.h` looks like this:

```
@interface Window : NSViewController{

    IBOutlet NSButton* button; 

}

@property (retain, readwrite) IBOutlet NSTableView *dataTableView;

-(IBAction) click :(id) sender;
```

`Window.m` looks like this:

```
@synthesize dataTableView;

-(void) awakeFromNib {

    g->dataTableViewGlobal =  self.dataTableView;
    [g->dataTableViewGlobal  setBackgroundColor: NSColor.redColor];
}

-(IBAction) click :(id) sender {

    [ g->dataTableViewGlobal setBackgroundColor: NSColor.blueColor];

    return;
}
```

The problem I am currently having (besides using a global variable) is that I am able to change the color of the NSTAbleView that is part of my nib during `awakeFromNib` using `dataTableViewGlobal`, but when I try to change the color in `click` nothing happens.

What I plan to do is use the global variable in other nibs that are created at the same time as `Window`. What I would prefer to do is have objects of `Window`that contains the current instance of `Window` where I need it in my code, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your IBAction is not properly connected to the button. So just make sure that it should be properly connected to the button.

After that modify the below action method:-

```
-(IBAction) click :(id) sender 
{
    g->dataTableViewGlobal =  self.dataTableView;
    [ g->dataTableViewGlobal setBackgroundColor: NSColor.blueColor];
}
```

Comment: My IBAction is fine. If I use `dataTableView` in `click` everything is fine.

Comment: Did you try this both two line in your action method?? g->dataTableViewGlobal =  self.dataTableView;
    [g->dataTableViewGlobal  setBackgroundColor: NSColor.redColor];

Comment: Adding `g->dataTableViewGlobal = self.dataTableView;` to my action method allows the color to be changed, but I want to use `dataTableViewGlobal` outside of the current class so I cannot set it to `self.dataTableView`.